# iPhone multi view/window switch

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibarbuttonitem

I've now put all night and tried to get my iPhone program to perform as intended, it has also succeed me sometimes but now I have pages with a problem I simplehen can not get resolved.

've tried this video guide that makes it I want it to but I stare my project up with NSObject (Windows Based) for my program.

Has anyone any. can help me a little further here? or link to come there can get me on track again

link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GeazgOqKJ4

Answer (score 0):

U can change that NSObject to UIView while selecting the view itself,
Just Right click classes-->Add Files-->in that dialog box, the bottom section contains a dropdown list box from there u can select ur required Type....